# Javascript to remove complex div in qml

Tags: javascript, html, webview, qml

```
<div class="hh"><div class="ih" onclick="return koya.onEvent(arguments[0]||window.event,'3_2')"><div class="jh kh"></div></div></div>
```

Hello, I am working with a qml webview element and I want to remove a div from the loaded page . I use the function webView.evaluateJavascript() to run the javascript code. Now I googled very much and tried different JavaScript codes to remove the div, but I failed.
Can someone tell how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have jquery loaded you can do something like this:

```
$(".ih").remove();
```

Where the . is followed by the class that exists on the div you want to remove.

If you don't have jquery loaded look into using getElementsByClassName

`var child = document.getElementsByClassName('ih')[0];
child.parent.removeChild(child);`